# Social media icon set that includes Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, icons

I'd like to add buttons to my blog that link to Twitter, LinkedIn, and Stack Overflow. There are tons of nice social media icon sets out there, but I've yet to find one that includes Stack Overflow. Has anyone seen one?

I'm not trying to post to Stack Overflow from an external site. I just want to link to my profile.

At Adam Davis's suggestion, I requested someone add one to a set I liked, and he did. [You can get them here](http://wplift.com/freebie-70-32px-custom-social-media-website-icons).

Comment: You can't share and post a link to Stack Overflow

Comment: @Eight I don't think he wants a "Post on StackOverflow" button akin to a "Tweet this post" button, I think he wants to link to SO or his SO profile with a nice image (like linking to his Twitter profile with a Twitter icon).

Comment: Must be because even outside icon sites know Stack Exchange isn't a social media swamp

Comment: @random not sure what your point is. I'm trying to do something stackexchange clearly condones. I just don't want to use the huge flair images. I'd rather have a consistent set of icons that link to my profiles on a few sites.

Comment: @chrispix I realize this is an old question, but I found a pack that includes Stack Overflow: [Vector Social Media Icons](http://icondock.com/free/vector-social-media-icons). Scroll until you see "Update #4."

Comment: Thanks @MattRefghi, that's a nice set. There's also a set at http://wplift.com/freebie-70-32px-custom-social-media-website-icons.

Comment: There is also a 64px PNG icon here: http://dinochiesa.net/   There is not a full set of icons - only a handful. But they're the most important ones!  I started with the Stucco icon set (google it) and added a few others.

Comment: There's also this set, which includes Stack Overflow: http://paulrobertlloyd.com/2009/06/social_media_icons/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're asking for a way to link to specific posts or just the site in general; I'm assuming it's the latter.

You can use [flair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/214350/chrispix?tab=flair) if you want it to link to your profile:

[image]

If you want something non-user-specific, you can pull the site logo from [here](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png) and make it a link:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to link to my profile. I was looking at icon sets because I'd rather have a consistent set of icons. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: you can download the vector format on our [logos page](http://stackexchange.com/about/logos) as well.

Comment: @Jin Are there plans to add logos for *all* of the Stack Exchange sites rather than just the trilogy?

Comment: @Chris it may get too crowded on that page for all SE sites. We plan to have a page off each SE site, with all the media files in the future.

Answer (score 10):

Update #4 to the [Vector Social Media Icons Pack](http://icondock.com/free/vector-social-media-icons) from Icon Dock includes a Stack Overflow icon:

[image: Check out the SO icon]

Comment: Hm, I don't see any that are 48x48 or larger...

Answer (score 5):

> There are tons of nice social media icon sets out there, but I've yet to find one that includes StackOverflow. Anyone seen one?

No, I've not seen a set that includes stack overflow, however we have a lot of pixel wranglers in our midst.

If you choose a common set that is popular, and ask someone to make a matching stackoverflow icon, I bet someone would oblige, especially if you made it trivial for them by providing example images, and the sizes they would need to output.

Answer (score 4):

Try using [Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/search?q=stack-overflow&o=r). It provides all kind of brand logos.

Answer (score 4):

## GitHub & Commons

Here are two more:

One is my icon set I just updated on GitHub: [github.com/JesseSteele/socicons](https://github.com/JesseSteele/socicons)

These are "flat" (all-black or all-white), open-source icons in "layers" of an .svg file. One may need a little knowledge of "vector" editors, like Adobe Illustrator or Inkscape to use this file, but it is useful for graphic designers. I needed an SE icon for my own websites and found this Question searching for one. So, I'm sharing here.

The other is the source I got the raw file from, [WikiMedia Commons: Stack Exchange icon](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Stack_Exchange_icon.svg)

Answer (score 3):

[This set](http://www.dreamtemplate.com/dreamcodes/documentation/social_icons.html) also includes a Stack Overflow icon.